# What statistical test should I use to assess changes in Likert scale over 3 points in time?

Tags: spss, survey, likert, research-design

I had a group of participants that provided responses to a 7-point Likert scale question at 3 points in time (baseline, immediately after a course, and 1 year after the course). What statistical test is best to assess for significant differences in their responses between those 3 points in time? I'm new to analyzing data and have just learned the basics of SPSS so I'm trying to figure out how to assess this most appropriately.

Comment: How did you calculate the sample size needed ?

Comment: I did not calculate sample size. This was not originally intended to be a study, it was just to collect feedback on the course, so we surveyed all participants who enrolled in the course. I understand this is a major limitation but still am just trying to identify what tests might be appropriate besides just a descriptive analysis. My sample size is 84 participants

Comment: Looks like a place for one of the may types of ordinal longitudinal models.  Two of them are Markov models and random effects ordinal models.  You might get lucky and have GEE with an after-the-fit intro-cluster correlation correction work when fitting ordinary univariate ordinal models.